# CentOS Postfix Server Hanging on NULL Recipients

Tags: linux, centos, postfix, centos6

I have a CentOS server that runs postfix and whenever a null recipient is sent to it, the server freaks out. Instead of simply rejecting the mail, it doesn't know what to do with it and tries over and over again and if enough of these pile up, then it pegs the CPU.

The front end is from a vendor and apparently cannot be changed so I'm stuck with this crappy problem. The users don't enter an email address and it comes unglued.

What can I change in my postfix config that will automatically reject these null recipient addresses?

Comment: Exactly what is Postfix doing? "Freaks out" is not a technical term...

Comment: It continually is attempting to figure out where to send the message, which cannot be sent. It's trying to find MX records for a null domain.

Comment: Where are your log entries then?

Comment: This logs in maillog. What does that have to do with rejecting the null domain?

Comment: Are you saying it accepts mail for `<>`?

Comment: Yes, it appears that's exactly what it's doing.

Comment: Your `main.cf` would be useful. As would a queue trace of one of these message from your `maillog`. The options on `smtpd` from `master.cf` may also help.

Comment: Here's what I'm seeing in mailog:

postfix/smtpd[1780]: warning: Illegal address syntax from localhost[127.0.0.1] in RCPT command: <>

Comment: And my main.cf and master.cf are at defaults

Comment: **This is not a forum** and you should not treat it as such. You should provide at least as much information as necessary for us to figure out what your issue is, _especially_ after being asked for it. Please see [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/126632) for details on how to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Postfix does know what to do with those messages: *reject them*, which is what it's doing. Your server may be under load, but it's trying to deliver a message for `<>` that it didn't accept in the first place.

You should really figure out why the client keeps trying to send messages to `<>` and have it stop doing that. It seems like the client is some sort of `MUA`. A proper `MTA` would have bounced the message back to sender after receiving a `5xx` response.

---

### client interaction

```
telnet server.example.com 25
mail from: <user@example.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: <>
501 5.1.3 Bad recipient address syntax
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
closed
```

---

### `maillog`

```
Sep  5 15:00:43 server postfix/smtpd[22395]: connect from  client.example.com[198.51.100.43]
Sep  5 15:01:09 server postfix/smtpd[22395]: warning: Illegal address syntax from  client.example.com[198.51.100.43] in RCPT command: <>
Sep  5 15:01:21 server postfix/smtpd[22395]: disconnect from client.example.com[198.51.100.43]
```